# Connecting ports by name in VHDL, UCF-style

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I have a VHDL entity defined like this:

```
entity RealEntity is
  port(
    CLK_50MHZ: in std_logic;
    LED : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end RealEntity;
```

If I also have UCF entries for `LED<0>..LED<3>` and `CLK_50MHZ`, then I can compile this entity directly.

However, I don't actually have a 50 MHz clock on my board, so I have to use a clock manager chip. I'm using Xilinx tools for this which has a wizard to add a DCM core, and then I wrap it in another VHDL entity for easy use:

```
entity dcm is
  port(
    CLK_32MHZ: in std_logic;
    CLK_50MHZ: out std_logic
    );
end dcm;
```

where `CLK_32MHZ` is something that actually exists in my UCF.

To connect these two, I am currently using a third entity to be used as my toplevel one:

```
entity main is
  port(
    CLK_32MHZ : in  std_logic;
    LED       : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end main;

architecture arch of main is
  signal CLK_50MHZ : std_logic;

  component dcm
    port(
      CLK_32MHZ : in  std_logic;
      CLK_50MHZ : out std_logic
      );
  end component;

  component RealEntity
    port(CLK_50MHZ : in  std_logic;
         LED       : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
         );
  end component;

begin
  inst_dcm : dcm
    port map(
      CLK_32MHZ => CLK_32MHZ,
      CLK_50MHZ => CLK_50MHZ
      );

  inst_RealEntity : RealEntity
    port map(
      CLK_50MHZ => CLK_50MHZ,
      LED       => LED
      );

end arch;
```

As you can see, this third entity is 100% boilerplate.
My question is, is it possible to avoid writing this `main` entity, and instead just use `RealEntity` and `dcm` directly, and connect the two `CLK_50MHZ` ports by virtue of them sharing their name, basically emulating `CLK_50MHZ` being present in my UCF file?

Comment: VHDL does not provide such an implicit connection based on port/signals names.  Designers sometimes makes their own tools to generate code for automatic creation of such connectivity modules.

Comment: Fair enough; if the answer is negative, that's also useful! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Also, I'll whip up a code generator for this if that is my best bet.

Comment: In Sigasi (http://www.sigasi.com) you can use quick-fixes to automatically declare the missing signal declarations.

Comment: @Cactus: It is inherently difficult to say that something is not possible, since tools may have feature that supplement the VHDL language.  Also, I am also curious to see what others will say, so I added the "Xilinx" tag to see if this could attract more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow you have to tell the tools how to wire up your DCM and your real entity.  Your "boilerplate" top-level entity is what achieves that.  You can't do it in the UCF file as it doesn't allow you to *create* connections, just attach various attributes to the connections that you have made.

So your problem then becomes one of what tools exist to enable you to "wire things up" as efficiently as possible.  Brian has enumerated some options for you there...

You can **reduce** your boilerplate by using direct instantiation.  Remove your `component` declarations and then do:

```
inst_RealEntity : entity work.RealEntity
    port map(
      CLK_50MHZ => CLK_50MHZ,
      LED       => LED
      );
```

Comment: I ended up using direct instantiation (which I didn't know about) on the DCM only, and changed my code generator to edit the `RealEntity` code to include that instantiation. For the curious, the code is here: https://github.com/gergoerdi/kansas-lava-papilio/blob/master/src/Hardware/KansasLava/Boards/Papilio/DCM.hs

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any such facility in the language itself, and I would rather not see such "implicit connections" as being too fragile. Often the top level is not **quite** boilerplate but an adaptor layer, and such implicit connections would then lead to too many unintended mistakes.

There are tools to simplify creating the boilerplate top level : Mentor Graphics "Renoir" *cough* ["HDL Designer"](http://www.mentor.com/products/fpga/hdl_design/hdl_designer_series/) is one such tool that automatically creates it from a block diagram : which you can think of as compilable documentation... Expensive though.

I have never personally got along with Emacs, but I would expect it to get pretty close to creating the boilerplate for you : and there, I would *encourage* it to create default "implicit connections" for you, as saving you work and still giving you final control.

[Sigasi](http://www.sigasi.com/) has also been mentioned and is well worth a look.

And I would be interested in hearing about other tools to accomplish the same.